# Is support for custom git-* commands documented?

Tags: git

I recently discovered that executable files on the `$PATH` that are prefixed with `git-` can be executed using the `git` program.  For instance, if file `git-custom-command-test` is on the path, it can be called using `git custom-command-test`.

```
$ printf '#!/usr/bin/env bash\necho "Successfully executed a custom Git command"' > git-custom-command-test
$ chmod u+x git-custom-command-test
$ export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)
$ git custom-command-test
Successfully executed a custom Git command
```

An Internet search has revealed that this is a known thing that exists, but I haven't found any definitive Git source documenting it.  For instance, I have not found a reference to it in [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).  It is very likely the failure is in my search.

Is this capability documented anywhere official?  And for that matter, is this an officially supported or recommended mechanism for adding custom commands?

Comment: it is surprisingly badly documented. I remember another SO question in the same spirit but can't find it back at the moment.

Comment: @LeGEC I didn't have luck finding a duplicate SO question, but it's very possible I missed one.

Comment: And, yes, the behavior is by design and absolutely supported.

Comment: Originally this was all git did. All git commands where separate programs and the git utility just allowed you to call them more conveniently. Only much later where a few basic commands integrated into the single git executable itself.

Answer (score 3):

At least somewhat indirectly.

```
$ man git
...
--list-cmds=group[,group...]

List commands by group. This is an internal/experimental option and may
change or be removed in the future. Supported groups are: builtins,
parseopt (builtin commands that use parse-options), main (all commands
in libexec directory), others (all other commands in $PATH that have
git- prefix), list-<category> (see categories in command-list.txt),
nohelpers (exclude helper commands), alias and config (retrieve
command list from config variable completion.commands)
```

Relevant is `others`:

```
, others (all other commands in $PATH that have
git- prefix)
```

So you can list all third-party commands with `git --list-cmds=others`.